# AngularMaterial - How to set background-color : accent in css or scss?

Tags: css, themes, angular-material

I have a table in AngularMaterial (5.x) and I need to set a hover and a selected row background color using primary and accent colors defined by themes.

But I can't call in my css   `background-color: mat-color($accent);` as it's telling me that $accent is not defined.

I tried to add `@import '~@angular/material/theming';` but still get the issue.
I get a look at [Angular Material Theming](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components) but didn't find a solution.

Can you please help me ?

Thanks for your help !
Regards,
Mike

Comment: What is your code? No one can help you without the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for didn't providing the code. Finally I use theming and I got what I need. Here is my code:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the theme.
$my-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$my-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$my-app-theme:   mat-light-theme($my-app-primary, $my-app-accent);

// Include the default theme styles.
@include angular-material-theme($my-app-theme);

@mixin mat-icon-size($size: 24px) {
    font-size: $size;
    height: $size;
    width: $size;
    line-height: $size;
}

.table-row:hover {
    background-color: mat-color($my-app-accent, 50);
}

.selected-row {
    background-color: mat-color($my-app-accent, 200);
}
```

And here is my list-component.html:

```
    <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
          <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" [checked]="isAllSelected()" [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
          </mat-checkbox>
        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <mat-checkbox class="small-icon" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row.sName) : null"
            [checked]="selection.isSelected(row.sName)">
          </mat-checkbox>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="RowId">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Id </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.sRowId}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.sName}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [class.selected-row]="selection.isSelected(row.sName)" (click)="selection.toggle(row.sName)"
        class="table-row"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

It's not very clean for the moment but it works.